# Configure PBX to forward calls to my phone only when home

Tags: asterisk

I want to configure a PBX (Yate or Asterisk or SIP Witch) so that when I'm away, it takes the call and tells the caller I'm not home, but when I'm home it forwards the call to my phone, which I connect via SIP-Account. Is that possible? What do I change in the config files to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is posible, but that require programming skills

Without programming skill you have only one variant: when you go out of home, you turn off your sip softphone on phone -> it send call to vm(becuase softphone is unreachable)

Possible variants with programming skills

1) check ip address of softphone. if it have address of home wifi, call.

2) check on home router if your phone is at home

3) use bluetooth or access card.

Answer (score 0):

I do the call forwarding at home. The advantage of doing the call forwarding at asterisk level, is that you can also forward the call to a SIP extension to a voIP account anywhere. (in my iPhone)

Let´s supposed your inbound number is: 211111111 and the forwarding extension is 500:

For that, you add to your dial plan `extensions.conf`.

```
exten => 211111111,1,Dial(SIP/500)
exten => 211111111,10,Hangup
```

For the taking the call when not answering, you have to activate voice mail in `users.conf`:

```
[500]
...
hasvoicemail = yes
```